# I want to know when a managed package is updated in my org

Tags: managed-package

Recently we had an issue and it went unnoticed for a while because one of the managed package was updated and its own settings was changed / removed. Is there a way in Salesforce org I can get notified when a managed package is changed / updated for my org?

Thanks,

Comment: You can ask the publisher to put you on the excluded list for automatic upgrades if that is how it is getting upgraded

Answer (score 0):

I would think about post install script implementation.
Try to write a class in the package which implements InstallHanlder and then send an email to you or your company.

There is a good example of this here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/apex_post_install_script_create.htm

If I didn't understand your purpose, please reply with your rejects.

Comment: I believe the post is for the publisher / manager of the app. I am at the subscriber end.